# Get an Nth filename of a directory in a variable in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to read the Nth filename of a directory into a variable.

```
for %%f in (%directory%\*.bmp) do set filename=%%~nf
```

will give the last filename.

Is it possible to use a counter to get for example the third filename in the directory?

Comment: You'd need to combine that counter with an `if` statement, but I don't see why not.

Comment: I would suggest that you use one or more commands within the parentheses to first sort the files into an appropriate order such that your intended file lies in the correct position.

Comment: How exactly is the Nth file in any directory interesting to you?

Comment: I've a directory with a variable number of pictures. I try to realise a batch file that can use one picture after the other (in both directions)

Comment: I've a directory with a variable number of pictures.
I try to realise a batch file that can use one picture after the other (in both directions) to use it in other batch files.
I tried to introduce a counter in the loop, but it's not updated during the loop.

    for %%f in (%directory%\*.bmp) do (
 set /a Counter+=1
 echo %Counter%
 if %counter% EQU 3 then filename=%%~nf
 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d "%directory%\*.bmp"^|findstr /n /r "."') do if %%f==%num% set filename=%%~ng
```

Perform a directory-listing in basic form without directory-names. Number each line with a preceding `num:`. Tokenise using `:` into `%%f`=line number, `%%g`=filename. Select the file number in `%num%`.

---

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
cls
SET /a count=3
FOR %%a IN (*.bmp) DO (
 SET /a count-=1
 CD .
 SET /a $=1/count >NUL 2>NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo ---%%a) ELSE (ECHO %%a)
)

GOTO :eof
```

This is likely faster. Adapt the principle to suit.

`%%a` gets each name in turn, and the counter is decremented. The `cd .` forces `errorlevel` to `0`. Then attempt to divide 1 by the count, which will fail if `count` is `0`. Suppress error messages.

if then `errorlevel` is 1 or greater, the division failed so the required filename is detected. If it is zero well - I just reported the file with no indicator.

Naturally, you could `set filename=%a&goto done` where `:done` is a label outside of the `for` loop if you require.

Comment: I finished more or less my batch file, the solution of Magoo works perfect, but..... it's pretty slow. Is there anyway to speed up this command?

Comment: Wow Magoo, you're amazing!! With some small adaptions, the result is immediat. Bef

Comment: Before I needed more then 3sec for 9 filenames, now it's just immediately. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: As said, works great. Is there any way to order the selection in alphabetical way, Now I get the oldest file first and the newest file last.